# How to find specific tags and values from a large XML file?

Tags: xml, shell

Can Anyone help to get specific XML tags and values from a running log file(for example abcdefg.log)?
*running log file contains a large number of SOAP requests and responses.

I tried this using the text processing tool such as grep and cut command but it did not give the output as I expected.

The Log file - abcdefg.log  contains many XML files(requests/responses) like below:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns7:newIdcreation xmlns:ns7="http://medip.ws.inops">
         <ns7:newIdcreation xmlns:ns1="http://medip.ws.inopss/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/4001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns1:newIdcreationRequestMsg">
            <ns1:requestHeader>
               <ns1:appIp>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</ns1:appIp>
               <ns1:appName>abc</ns1:appName>
               <ns1:passWord>abc</ns1:passWord>
               <ns1:userName>abc</ns1:userName>
            </ns1:requestHeader>
            <ns1:createInitialSubscriberRequest xsi:type="ns1:CreateNewSubscriberRequest">
               <ns1:subscriberNumber>3331260097</ns1:subscriberNumber>
               <ns1:IM>890045112109331</ns1:IM>
               <ns1:commonProperty>
                  <ns1:billCycleType>20</ns1:billCycleType>
                  <ns1:clubVisionID />                 
                  <ns1:customerAddress>add</ns1:customerAddress>
                  <ns1:customerGender>8050000</ns1:customerGender>
                  <ns1:customerName>bb</ns1:customerName>
                  <ns1:cxCatogary>MC</ns1:cxCatogary>
                  <ns1:CreditType>RAY</ns1:cxCreditType>
                  <ns1:cxPriority />
                  <ns1:Profiler>BB</ns1:cxProfiler>
                  <ns1:idCode>999900009999</ns1:idCode>
                  <ns1:idType>6050000</ns1:idType>
                  <ns1:language>7</ns1:language>
                  <ns1:CreditLimit>2000000</ns1:posCreditLimit>
               </ns1:commonProperty>
               <ns1:mainProductID>2000050212</ns1:mainProductID>
               <ns1:paidMod>3</ns1:paidMod>
            </ns1:createInitialSubscriberRequest>
         </ns7:newSubscriber>
      </ns7:newIdcreation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But, I Only need a few lines from these types of SOAP requests (XML):-
Is there any way to get only 4 tags in each SOAP request to the CLI?

Tags are:-
I want these 4 lines for further analysis

```
<ns7:newIdcreation xmlns:ns1="http://medip.ws.inopss/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/4001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns1:newIdcreationRequestMsg">
<ns1:subscriberNumber>3331260097</ns1:subscriberNumber>
<ns1:CreditType>RAY</ns1:cxCreditType>
<ns1:paidMod>3</ns1:paidMod>
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question as your efforts, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can list all contents of your xml file using the "cat" command.
Create a pipe and use the "grep" command in order to search for your tags.

Using the "-n" parameter allows you to see the linenumber of the tag.
The "-E" parameter, allows grep to intepret your input as an extended-regular-expression.
With the "|" (pipe) symbol you can search for multiple patterns.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
cat file.xml | grep -n -E "<ns1:paidMod>|<ns1:CreditType>|<ns1:subscriberNumber>|<ns7:newIdcreation"
```